# Use inner join and left join with more than 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here you can see I have three tables

Student table

```
Stud_id   Name       Br_id    Email         City_id
1001      Ankit     101     ankit@bmail.com     1
1002      Pranav    105     pranav@bmail.com    2
1003      Raj       102     raj@bmail.com       2
1004      Shyam     112     shyam@bmail.com     4
1005      Duke      112      duke@bmail.com     2
1006      Jhon      102     jhon@bmail.com      3
1007      Aman      101     aman@bmail.com      4
1008      Pavan     111    pavan@bmail.com      13
1009      Virat     112    virat@bmail.com      12
```

Branch Table

```
Br_id   Br_name  HOD        Contact
101     CSE     SH Rao      22345
102     MECH    AP Sharma   28210
103     EXTC    VK Reddy    34152
104     CHEM    SK Mehta    45612
105     IT      VL Shelke   22521
106     AI      KH Verma    12332
107     PROD    PG Kakde    90876
```

Address Table

```
City_id   City       Pincode
1         Mumbai    400121
2         Pune      450011
3         Lucknow   553001
4         Delhi     443221
5         Kolkata   213445
6         Chennai   345432
7         Nagpur    323451
8         Sri Nagar 321321
```

I am using here three tables first one is a student table and the second one is a Branch table and the third one is an Address table

So I am writing a query like this here you can see below

```
    select [Name], Br_name, City 
    from student
    inner join Branch on student.Br_id = Branch.Br_id
    left join [Address] on student.City_id = [Address].City_id
```

I have three tables I want to show here the student's name and branch name city name, but I want to show the student who has their branch only. I also want to show the student who has their city as well as show a student who does not have any city.

I wrote the query above but here I am not getting the result. Here student's name who does not have any city what's wrong here in my above join SQL query?

Here as  you can see I am getting this  result which I do not want to show

```
    Name    Br_name   City
    Ankit   CSE      Mumbai
    Pranav  IT       Pune
    Raj     MECH     Pune
    Jhon    MECH     Lucknow
    Aman    CSE      Delhi
```

Why can I not get the students who do not have a city and who have a city? What's wrong here in my join query what I am missing here?

Please let me know what's wrong in my above join query what should I do to get proper result? I have given three tables above

You  can see that and why I am not able to get the result what I want to show what is the wrong in the above my join query please let me know

I hope someone will help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don't keep asking the same question over and over. If you're not getting an answer its because the question isn't clear. And in fact I asked for additional information on your last question which you failed to provide.

Comment: In fact this is the third time you have asked this question - and you accepted an answer on the first.

Comment: i have provided tables

Comment: You need to edit your previous question with this information, because this question is now closed. And I recommend getting familiar with the editing UI because I have had to edit your questions to make the text text instead of code.

Comment: **There are no students in your tables who have a branch but no city.** Students 1001 to 1007 have both a branch and a city; students 1008 and 1009 have both no branch and no city.

Comment: Better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74134128/edit) your request you made before and which is still open. Copy and paste the tables you are showing here to that other request. Add a student with a branch and no city. And show the expected result.

Comment: do you try query bellow : only get students have branch or city :

select [Name], Br_name, City 
    from student
    left join Branch on student.Br_id = Branch.Br_id
    left join [Address] on student.City_id = [Address].City_id
where (Branch.Br_id is not null or [Address].City_id is not null)

Comment: it does not work

Comment: why name is not showing here whose city id is 13 and 12 here

Comment: query should be like this 
select [Name], Br_name, City from student
left join Branch on student.Br_id = Branch.Br_id
left join [Address] on student.City_id = [Address].City_id
where (Branch.Br_name is null or [Address].City is not  null)